# How do I permanantly unistall nmap?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos

Installed nmap from https://nmap.org/download.html to check it out, got bored, moved the app name: zenmap to trash and emptied it. However, if I run the `nmap` command in terminal, it still works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `nmap` installer from https://nmap.org/download.html installs

- the application `/Applications/Zenmap.app`
- some binaries in `/usr/local/bin`
- support files in other directories within `/usr/local`

To remove, run

```
sudo rm -r /Applications/Zenmap.app
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/{ncat,ndiff,nmap,nmap-update,nping}
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/*/man1/nmap.1
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/{ncat,ndiff,nping,nmap-update}.1
sudo rm -r /usr/local/share/{nmap,ncat}
```